# Quintus - dynamic sprite stacking order

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using the html5 quintus js game library. According to 
http://www.html5quintus.com/guide/sprites.md#.Va7FBPmznN4
the p.z can be used to change a sprite's stacking order. But it doesn't seem to do anything for me.  I have insert multiple sprites in the same scene. My sprite is setup as this:

```
    Q.Sprite.extend("test", {
        init: function(p) {
            this._super(p,{
                asset: "smallship_1x2.png",
                x: 150, 
                y: 300,
        z : 0,
        dragging : false,
        offSet : {
        x:0,
        y:0
        }
            });
            this.on("drag");
        },
        drag: function(touch) {
            this.p.dragging = true;
    this.p.x = touch.origX + touch.dx;
    this.p.y = touch.origY + touch.dy;
    this.p.z = 10;
        }
    });
```

I added a few of the test sprites in the same stage, when I drag a sprite, i want it to have higher stacking order (so the sprite will appear to be on top of others in case i drag across other sprites), however it seems that setting the p.z  doesn't do anything.  I've tried initializing the sprite with higher number on the z property but it also doesn't do anything,  the stacking order seems to be solely based on the order that I insert them into the stage. (the last insert has the highest stacking order).

Does anyone know how to dynamically change the stacking order of sprites?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You have to set the stage object sort to true. You'll find info here: https://plus.google.com/communities/104292074755089084725/s/sort

Comment: @ericjbasti  Thanks!! that's just what i needed  ;)

Comment: you might want to leave an answer for the next person, showing how to set the Sort property. I don't use Quintus or I would put one.